# Cant Upload file CSV to database in hosting

Tags: php, mysql, csv, codeigniter-2

I have a code like this

```
function upload() {

    $this->db->empty_table('area_proses'); 

    $data['error'] = '';    //initialize image upload error array to empty

    $config['upload_path'] = './coba_upload/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
    $config['max_size'] = '20';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $data['level'] = $this->session->userdata('level_id');
    $data['email'] = $this->session->userdata('email');
    $data['include'] =   $this->load->view('/read/include','',TRUE);
    $data['content'] =   $this->load->view('/read/upload',$data,TRUE);
    $this->load->view("admin/main",$data);

    // If upload failed, display error
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        //$this->load->view('/read/upload', $data);
    } else {
        $file_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_path =  './coba_upload/'.$file_data['file_name'];

        if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path)) {
            $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);
            foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
                $insert_data = array(
                    'id'=>$row['id'],
                    'area_proses'=>$row['area_proses'],
                    'sg1'=>$row['sg1'],
                    'sg2'=>$row['sg2'],
                    'sg3'=>$row['sg3'],
                    'avg'=>$row['avg'],
                    'fuzzy'=>$row['fuzzy'],
                );
                    $this->model->insert_csv($insert_data);
                }
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Csv Data Imported Succesfully');
                redirect(base_url().'area_proses');
                    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($insert_data);
        } else
            $data['include'] =   $this->load->view('/read/include','',TRUE);
            $data['content'] =   $this->load->view('/read/upload',$data,TRUE);
            $this->load->view("admin/main",$data);
    }


}
```

The problem is i can upload a csv file to insert into databases in localhost (xampp) but when i hosting that, the code is not work, only delete a data and not a read csv to insert to databases

are you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check LOAD DATA INFILE to import a csv into a database.
It's better than a loop if your amount of data is huge.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html